# using animate package for create map animation

Tags: r, dictionary, animation, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate an map animation showing the president voting outcome of each state from 1990 to 2012. **My goal is to add Year to the title of the animation so that reader know which year corresponds to the each frame.** However, I keep getting err msg that I cannot understand.

Any help in how to resolve this problem is greatly appreciated!

```
library(choroplethr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(gganimate)
library(maps)

#download president data
data("df_president_ts")

us <- map_data("state")

elections <- df_president_ts %>%
  #gather into long data
  gather(year, winner, `1789`:`2012`) %>%
  #filter only elections after 1900
  filter(year >= 1900) %>%
  #join with state polygons
  right_join(us, by = "region") %>%
  mutate(party = case_when(
    winner %in% c("SR", "I", "AI", "PR") ~ "Third Party",
    winner == "D" ~ "Democrat",
    winner == "R" ~ "Republican"
  ))
elections$year=as.integer(elections$year)  # convert year from character to integer

## the original code on the website:
p1 <- ggplot(data = elections, aes(frame = year)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = party),
               color = "#f5f5f2") +
  theme_map() +
  coord_map("albers", lat0=30, lat1=40) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#05204A", "#A24936", "#3E5641"), 
                    na.value = "gray70",
                    name = "Winning Party") +
  ggtitle("US Presidential Election Results: ")

gganimate(p1, interval = 1.5)

# it shows that Error: It appears that you are trying to use the old API, which has been deprecated.
# Please update your code to the new API or install the old version of gganimate
# from https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/releases/tag/v0.1.1


## THUS, I changed the code to following:
p1 <- ggplot(data = elections, aes(frame = year)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = party),
               color = "#f5f5f2") +
  coord_map("albers", lat0=30, lat1=40) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#05204A", "#A24936", "#3E5641"), 
                    na.value = "gray70",
                    name = "Winning Party") +
  ggtitle("US Presidential Election Results: ")+
  transition_manual(year)

animate(p1)


## The code below creates an animation, but I want to add year to the title so that each frame 
## corresponds to its own year.
p<-ggplot(data = elections,aes(frame=year)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = party)) +
  coord_map("albers", lat0=30, lat1=40) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#05204A", "#A24936", "#3E5641"), 
                    na.value = "gray70",
                    name = "Winning Party") 

g<-p+ transition_manual(year)+
  labs(title="US Presidential Election Results")
animate(g)

#I tried: ggtitle("US Presidential Election Results: {frame_time}"), but it does not work.
g<-p+ transition_manual(year)+
  labs(title="US Presidential Election Results: {frame_time}")
h<-animate(g,  renderer = gifski_renderer())


# I also tried the following, it gives an error msg: "Error in seq.default(range[1], range[2], length.out = nframes) : 
# 'from' must be a finite number. 
g<-p + transition_time(year) +
  labs(title = "US Presidential Election Results:{frame_time}")
h<-animate(g)

# lastly, I tried this, but it creates the same err msg: "rror in seq.default(range[1], range[2], length.out = nframes):
# 'from' must be a finite number. 
p<-ggplot(data = elections) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = party)) +
  coord_map("albers", lat0=30, lat1=40) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#05204A", "#A24936", "#3E5641"), 
                    na.value = "gray70",
                    name = "Winning Party") 
g<-p + transition_time(year) +
  labs(title = "US Presidential Election Results:{frame_time}")
h<-animate(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

`aes(frame = year)` this is code for the old `gganimate`.

If you look at `?transition_manual` there is a section called "Label variables" which states what variables are available for titles.

```
p1 <- ggplot(elections, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = party)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "#f5f5f2") +
  #theme_map() +  #not sure where this is from
  coord_map("albers", lat0=30, lat1=40) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#05204A", "#A24936", "#3E5641"), 
                    na.value = "gray70",
                    name = "Winning Party") +
  transition_manual(year) +
  ggtitle("US Presidential Election Results: {current_frame}")

animate(p1, fps = 3)
```

I agree that the error messages aren't always particularly useful in figuring this out, but the documentation itself is quite thorough.

[image]